# How do I create an array of enums in a JSON avro schema?

Tags: python, json, avro

I would like to have an avro schema that has a field called validExtensions.  How can I have validExtensions accept a list of enum extensions?

I created a list of acceptable extensions in an enum:

```
    {
    "type":"enum",
    "name":"extensions",
    "symbols": [".zip",".txt",".csv",".pdf",".xls",".xlsx"]
    }
```

But I can't seem to figure out a way to have a field that accepts an array of enum values within extensions.  For example an json output would be:

```
{
 "data":{
    "validExtensions": [".csv", ".xls"],
    "fileName": "testing.csv"
        }
 }
```

Here's what I already tried but it does not work:

```
{
    "type":"record",
    "name":"data",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name":"validExtensions",
            "type":"array",
            "items": {
                "extensions"
                }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found something that works with an array of enums:

```
 {
   "type":"enum",
   "name":"Extensions",
   "symbols": [".zip",".txt",".csv"]
 }

 {
  "type":"record",
  "name":"data",
  "fields": [
    {
        "name": "key",
        "type": "string"
    {
        "name":"validExtensions",
        "type":{"type":"array", "items":"Extensions"}
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the issue

```
{
     "type": "record",
     "name": "data",
     "fields": [
        {
         "name": "key",
         "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "validExtensions",
      "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "enum",
          "name": "Extensions",
          "symbols": [
            ".zip",
            ".txt",
            ".csv"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).